# Magento 2 uiComponent multiple instance

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, knockout, uielement

I have a view with two templates that use the same uiComponent with Knockout Js.

I spent hours trying to discover how to do not share the observables between two different templates.

example:

```
<div id="inbox" class="inbox-wrapper" data-bind="scope:'inbox'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div id="other-inbox" class="other-inbox-wrapper" data-bind="scope:'otherinbox'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#inbox": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "inbox": {
                    "component": "Digibart_Notifications/js/component/inbox",
                    "template": "Digibart_Notifications/inbox",
                    "identifier": "<?= $block->getInboxIdentifier(); ?>",
                    "options": <?= $block->getJsonOptions();?>,
                    "elementId": "#inbox"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "#other-inbox": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
           "components": {
                "otherinbox": {
                    "component": "Digibart_Notifications/js/component/inbox",
                    "template": "Digibart_Notifications/otherinbox",
                    "identifier": "<?= $block->getInboxIdentifier(); ?>",
                    "options": <?= $block->getJsonOptions();?>,
                    "elementId": "#otherinbox"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: post your Digibart_Notifications/js/component/inbox code